# What does the minus/subtraction operator in front of function do in C++?

Tags: c++, function

I have seen people using the subtraction (the char '-') operator in front of a function. 
For example calling a function like this:

```
-myFunction(someParameter);
```

I don't know what this does, and Googleing it is not helping. 
Can anyone please explain what this does, or what it is called, so i will be able to google it properly. Thank you.

Comment: was this in a c++ code or an objective-C code?

Comment: The unary `-` is for negation. It will work by default with built in integral values. In such cases in means the same thing as in mathematics.

Comment: So whatever the function returns will be of negative value?

Comment: The type of the object returned by `myFunction` might well overload the unary operator -, possibly with side effects.

Comment: @JonasLomholdt: "function returns will be of negative value" - the negation reverses the sign, so if the function returns a negative value already then `-fn(...)` returns the corresponding positive/absolute value (if possible - some values like `char(-128)` may not have a corresponding positive value).  Re 0x499602D2's comment - it works for other types too, notably floating point types `float` and `double`.

Comment: Thank you for the replies! Asking here was the right thing to do.

Comment: @TonyD usual arithmetic conversions are applied to the operand of `-`, so if the function returns `char(-128)` then `-fn()` is `int(128)` . But your point applies if it were returning `int(INT_MIN)` etc.

Comment: @Jonas Lomholdt: a better thing to do would have been to just try it.

Comment: Thanks @B... I did that. But the underlying information would still be a black box to me. True, I could have formulated the question better, but by just trying I would never have been able to get excellent answers like the ones I have now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means that the function returns a type that can have the unary `-` (minus) operator applied to it.

```
int myFunction()
{
    return 42;
}

...

int x = -myFunction();
```

The value of `x` will be `-42` in the example above.